Problema con el envío de archivos DOTX del servidor al cliente en C# - Perdida de datos durante la transmisión
Tengo archivos subidos a Azure Blob Storage y quiero descargarlos en mi aplicación.
Tengo en mi .aspx un botón que ejecuta el método de descarga:
protected async void WebPagePopupDownloadDocumentButtonOnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    string rawJson = JsonResultHiddenField.Value;

    string unescapedJson = System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(rawJson).Trim('"');

    if (unescapedJson.StartsWith("\"") && unescapedJson.EndsWith("\""))
    {
        unescapedJson = unescapedJson.Substring(1, unescapedJson.Length - 2);
    }

    unescapedJson = unescapedJson.Replace("\\\"", "\"");

    unescapedJson = unescapedJson.Replace("\\r", "").Replace("\\n", "");

    try
    {
        var jsonObject = JObject.Parse(unescapedJson);
        string fileUrl = (string)jsonObject["Documents"]?[0]?["FileUrl"];
        if (fileUrl != null)
        {
            using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
            {
                string guidText = GuidLabel.Text;
                string guid = guidText.Substring(guidText.IndexOf(":") + 2).Trim();
                var configManager = Container.Resolve<IFeConfigManager>();
                var nawServicesUrl = configManager.GetModel<KeyValueConfig>(ConfigurationModels.SendToInfolex, ApplicationManager.Instance.RecoverProductId())["NawServicesUrl"];

                var accessToken = SessionManager.Instance.RecoverSession()?.OidcWorkflowData?.TokenResponseData?.AccessToken;
                httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);

                string fileName = Path.GetFileName(fileUrl);
                string url = $"{nawServicesUrl}{DOWNLOAD_DOCUMENT_OP}?guid={guid}&fileName={fileName}";

                var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(url);
                response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

                var fileBytes = await response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();

                Response.Clear();
                Response.ContentType = GetContentType(fileName);
                Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", $"attachment; filename={fileName}");
                Response.BinaryWrite(fileBytes);
                Response.End();

            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("No FileUrl found.");
        }
    }
    catch (JsonReaderException ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"JSON parse error: {ex.Message}");

    }

}

private string GetContentType(string fileName)
{
    string extension = Path.GetExtension(fileName).ToLower();
    switch (extension)
    {
        case ".pdf":
            return "application/pdf";
        case ".doc":
            return "application/msword";
        case ".docx":
            return "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document";
        case ".html":
            return "text/html";
        case ".dotx":
            return "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.template";
        default:
            return "application/octet-stream";

    }

En el código hago una llamada al servidor que se comunica con el Blob Storage para descargar el archivo. Actualmente puedo descargar archivos con diferentes formatos (HTML, PDF, DOCX, DOTX...) pero sólo puedo abrir sin problemas los archivos DOCX y DOTX.
Cuando intento abrir un archivo descargado DOCX, Microsoft Word me lanza el siguiente mensaje:

Si hago clic en "Sí", puedo abrir el archivo y visualizarlo.
Cuando intento abrir un archivo descargado DOCT, Microsoft Word me lanza el siguiente mensaje:

Y simplemente no me deja abrirlo.
He probado a descargar directamente desde el Blob Storage el archivo DOTX y puedo abrirlo sin problemas. Me he dado cuenta de que el archivo que descargo directamente desde el Blob Storage y el que descargo desde la aplicación tienen tamaños distintos. El que descargo desde la aplicación es más pequeño:

Comparando los archivos byte a byte con HxD he visto que son los últimos 10KB los que faltan.
He visto en Internet que es recomendable, sobre todo para archivos grandes (mi caso), hacer la descarga en el servidor en un directorio temporal y luego transmitir esta descarga al cliente. Probé entonces a hacer esto:
protected async void WebPagePopupDownloadDocumentButtonOnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    string rawJson = JsonResultHiddenField.Value;

    string unescapedJson = System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(rawJson).Trim('"');

    if (unescapedJson.StartsWith("\"") && unescapedJson.EndsWith("\""))
    {
        unescapedJson = unescapedJson.Substring(1, unescapedJson.Length - 2);
    }

    unescapedJson = unescapedJson.Replace("\\\"", "\"");

    unescapedJson = unescapedJson.Replace("\\r", "").Replace("\\n", "");

    try
    {
        var jsonObject = JObject.Parse(unescapedJson);
        string fileUrl = (string)jsonObject["Documents"]?[0]?["FileUrl"];
        if (fileUrl != null)
        {
            using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
            {
                string guidText = GuidLabel.Text;
                string guid = guidText.Substring(guidText.IndexOf(":") + 2).Trim();
                var configManager = Container.Resolve<IFeConfigManager>();
                var nawServicesUrl = configManager.GetModel<KeyValueConfig>(ConfigurationModels.SendToInfolex, ApplicationManager.Instance.RecoverProductId())["NawServicesUrl"];

                var accessToken = SessionManager.Instance.RecoverSession()?.OidcWorkflowData?.TokenResponseData?.AccessToken;
                httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);

                string fileName = Path.GetFileName(fileUrl);
                string url = $"{nawServicesUrl}{DOWNLOAD_DOCUMENT_OP}?guid={guid}&fileName={fileName}";

                var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(url);
                response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

                var fileBytes = await response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();

                string tempFilePath = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), fileName);
                File.WriteAllBytes(tempFilePath, fileBytes);

                Response.Clear();
                Response.ContentType = GetContentType(fileName);
                Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", $"attachment; filename={fileName}");
                Response.TransmitFile(tempFilePath);
                Response.End();
                File.Delete(tempFilePath);

            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("No FileUrl found.");
        }
    }
    catch (JsonReaderException ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"JSON parse error: {ex.Message}");

    }

}

private string GetContentType(string fileName)
{
    string extension = Path.GetExtension(fileName).ToLower();
    switch (extension)
    {
        case ".pdf":
            return "application/pdf";
        case ".doc":
            return "application/msword";
        case ".docx":
            return "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document";
        case ".html":
            return "text/html";
        case ".dotx":
            return "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.template";
        default:
            return "application/octet-stream";

    }

Donde básicamente hago una descarga en un path temporal y luego transmito esta descarga utilizando Response.TransmitFile(tempFilePath). El archivo descargado en este path temporal puedo abrirlo sin ningún problema, ya sea de tipo DOCX, DOTX o cualquiera de los otros. Sin embargo, si intento abrir el que envío al cliente (en "Descargas"), no puedo abrir los DOTX, puedo abrir los DOCX con el mensaje de "contenido ilegible" y sólo puedo abrir sin problemas los PDF y HTML.
También he probado a hacer la descarga de bytes asíncrona:
private async Task WriteBytesAsync(string filePath, byte[] bytes)
{
   using (var fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None, bufferSize: 4096, useAsync: true))
   {
       await fileStream.WriteAsync(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
   }
}

Y utilizar await WriteBytesAsync(tempFilePath, fileBytes) en vez de File.WriteAllBytes(tempFilePath, fileBytes), pero tampoco ha funcionado.
En conclusión, parece que hay algún problema a la hora de transmitir el archivo DOTX o sus bytes de información al cliente. He probado con manipular el Response con varios métodos pero tampoco ha funcionado.
Cualquier ayuda o consejo es bienvenido.
